# Changing date format - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column in my table named `expiry` which has type VARCHAR. In the column, there is a mixture of date format like **YYYY-MM-DD** and **MM-DD-YYYY**.

How can i re-arrange the format **MM-DD-YYYY** to **YYYY-MM-DD** in my laravel view blade ?

**View**

```
 @foreach($product_select as $key => $product)
   <tr>
   <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
   <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($product->expiry)->isoFormat('YYYY MM DD')}}</td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
```

In the view above, it throws an error

> > Could not parse '02-27-2021': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (02-27-2021) at position 0

How can i solve this ?

**Product Output**

```
{#3504 ▼
  +"product_id": "999"
  +"id": 999
  +"name": "CONFIDO    CONFIDO TABS 60'S HIMALAYA"
  +"code": "P935"
  +"expiry": "03-31-2023"
  +"type": "standard"
}
```

Comment: @Droid, i have updated the question with the output

Comment: Well, Carbon can't exactly guess on whether or not you use one format or the other. You'd have to be explicit or convert the formats to something parsable.

Comment: Try this`{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $product->expiry')->Format('Y m d')}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm actually going to just suggest that you stop storing date information in a text varchar column.  Instead, you should be using a proper MySQL date column.  Here is how you can rectify the situation from MySQL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE product ADD COLUMN new_expiry DATE;

UPDATE product
SET new_expiry = CASE WHEN expiry REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'
                      THEN CAST(expiry AS DATE)
                      ELSE STR_TO_DATE(expiry, '%m-%d-%Y') END;

ALTER TABLE product DROP COLUMN expiry;
ALTER TABLE product RENAME COLUMN new_expiry TO expiry;
```

I wouldn't even bother trying to manage this column from Laravel.  Even if someone gives you an answer, it will be ugly and a lot of work, and also not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($product->expiry)->format('YYYY MM DD')}}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

first provide current format

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", $product->expiry)->toDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you this if your date string is `m-d-Y` format

else update `varchar` to `date` in mysql as @tim-biegeleisen mentioned use that

```php
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $product->expiry')->isoFormat('YYYY MM DD')}}
```